# Swift make UIView border into Gradient Color

Tags: swift

I want to create a gradient border on a UIView.

The following code can produce a solid for the view Box1.

nothing I have found allows me to change the frameColor to a gradient.

```
    var frameColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    var leftBorder = CALayer()
    leftBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0, width: 1, height: box1.frame.size.height )
    leftBorder.backgroundColor = frameColor
```

I am using Swift 5 and Xcode 11.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try with below extension

```
public extension UIView {

private static let kLayerNameGradientBorder = "GradientBorderLayer"

func setGradientBorder(
    width: CGFloat,
    colors: [UIColor],
    startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0),
    endPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    ) {
    let existedBorder = gradientBorderLayer()
    let border = existedBorder ?? CAGradientLayer()
    border.frame = bounds
    border.colors = colors.map { return $0.cgColor }
    border.startPoint = startPoint
    border.endPoint = endPoint

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 0).cgPath
    mask.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    mask.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    mask.lineWidth = width

    border.mask = mask

    let exists = existedBorder != nil
    if !exists {
        layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}

func removeGradientBorder() {
    self.gradientBorderLayer()?.removeFromSuperlayer()
}

private func gradientBorderLayer() -> CAGradientLayer? {
    let borderLayers = layer.sublayers?.filter { return $0.name == UIView.kLayerNameGradientBorder }
    if borderLayers?.count ?? 0 > 1 {
        fatalError()
    }
    return borderLayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer
}
```

}

Usage

```
self.borderView.setGradientBorder(width: 5.0, colors: [UIColor.red , UIColor.blue])
```

[image]

I hope this will reach your requirement.

https://medium.com/@kushal0409/gradient-button-3dc8ef763039

Comment: I just want to apply to the top and left borders.  Maybe I can tweak the function?

Comment: Wow, did you have that extension lying around, or did you write it custom for this question? (I'm impressed either way. Voted.)

Comment: can this code be modified to just the individual borders.  top, bottom, left, right?  I have been playing with that without much success.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5 extension** (works with corner radius)

```
extension UIView {
    func gradientBorder(colors: [UIColor], isVertical: Bool){
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        //Create gradient layer
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.bounds.size)
        gradient.colors = colors.map({ (color) -> CGColor in
            color.cgColor
        })

        //Set gradient direction
        if(isVertical){
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        }
        else {
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        }

        //Create shape layer    
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.lineWidth = 1
        shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: gradient.frame.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1), cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradient.mask = shape

        //Add layer to view
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
        gradient.zPosition = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no off-the-shelf way to do this, but you could build it yourself.

Off the top of my head, the approach might look like this:

- Create a `CAGradientLayer` and set it up to draw your gradient as
  desired.
- Create a `CAShapeLayer` that contains an empty rectangle that is your
  frame.
- Add your shape layer as the mask of your gradient layer.
- Add the gradient layer to your view as a sub-layer of the view's
  content layer.

Comment: man, that is way about my simple pay grade and coding IQ.  this might take some work.  thank you.

Comment: It isn't as bad as it sounds. Start by creating a gradient layer and adding that to a custom view. Layers are quite powerful, and once you get the hang of them, not that hard to use.